# ios simulator not opening react native command line project mac

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, react-native, macos

I am trying to set up my development environment for a React Native project. `npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject` finally worked after upgrading Node to version 18, but the ios simulator will not open with my project when running `npx react-native run-ios`.

I am expecting the simulator to open with my project after running npx react-native run-ios. I have tried so many things, changing node/ruby versions, running `bundle install` and `bundle exec pod install` in the ios folder. Running `npx react-native run-ios` nothing happens. I'm trying to get this to work on a macbook 13.4

If I try to use a different version of node (16.14.0) the bundler install step fails during init:

✖ Installing Bundler
error Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

And yes I went in to Xcode and selected the command line tools...

---

EDIT: I changed back to 16.14 and init a new project. The bundler failed to install again. I ran bundle install and bundle exec pod install in pod folder, went back to main folder and ran the project. After about ten minutes the simulator booted up. I don't think this is working very well, however. The number of errors encountered trying to set up the dev env. is ridiculous. I think it would be nice if there was a posting of versions that work well together.

Answer (score 0):

**Simulator not opening:**

- Ensure Xcode is installed on your Mac and updated to the latest
  version.
- Open Xcode, go to "Preferences" from the "Xcode" menu and select
  the "Locations" tab. Ensure the Command Line Tools field is set to
  a valid Xcode version.
- Double-check that you have    selected a simulator as the default in
  Xcode's preferences (as mentioned in the previous response).
- Try running the simulator directly from Xcode to ensure it is
  functioning correctly (as mentioned in step 3 of the previous
  response).
- If the simulator still doesn't open, check the system logs (Console.
  app) for any error messages related to the simulator or Xcode. This
  might provide additional information about the issue.

**Node.js version and bundler issues:**

- Upgrading Node.js to version 18 might have introduced compatibility
  issues with some dependencies. It's recommended to use a stable
  version of Node.js that is officially supported by the React Native
  ecosystem. Currently, Node.js version 14.x is the Long-Term Support
  (LTS) release.
- To switch to Node.js version 14.x, you can use a version manager like
  nvm (Node Version Manager) to install and manage multiple Node.js
  versions on your machine. Refer to the nvm documentation for
  instructions on how to switch to a specific Node.js version.
- After switching to Node.js version 14.x using nvm, delete the
  node_modules directory of your React Native project and reinstall the
  dependencies by running `npm install` or `yarn install` again.
- Try running the React Native project using `npx react-native run-ios`
  again to see if the simulator opens successfully.

**Bundler install error with Node.js version 16.14.0:**

- If you need to use Node.js version 16.x, ensure that you have the
  necessary build tools installed on your system. On macOS, you can
  install the Xcode command line tools by running the following command
  in the terminal: xcode-select --install.
- Additionally, make sure you have the appropriate version of Ruby and
  its dependencies installed. You can use a version manager like rbenv
  or rvm to manage your Ruby versions.
- Before running `npx react-native init`, try running `bundle install` and
  `bundle exec pod install` separately in the ios directory of your React
  Native project. This will ensure that the required Ruby gems are
  installed for iOS development.